# Update timestamp field in MongoDB and Golang Driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using official MongoDb Driver for Golang. I have a field with timestamp type which I want to update from my Golang code.

This is my struct (lastUpdate field is the timestamp field):

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)


type MyStruct struct {
    Id primitive.ObjectID  `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Alias  string `json:"alias"`
    Signed bool   `json:"signed"`
    Age int   `json:"age"`
    CreatedDate time.Time   `json:"createdDaate"`
    LastUpdate primitive.Timestamp `json:"lastUpdate"`
}
```

Then I pass this bson to update my data:

```
    // logic to update data
    docID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("5de30185e4fabe4778f0ffdf")

    UpdateMyData(c, bson.M{"createdDate": time.Now(), "lastUpdate": time.Now().UnixNano() }, bson.M{"_id": docID})

 //update method
func UpdateMyData(client *mongo.Client, updatedData bson.M, filter bson.M) int64 {
    collection := client.Database("*****").Collection("*****")
    atualizacao := bson.D{ {Key: "$set", Value: updatedData} }
    updatedResult, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, atualizacao)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error on updating one Hero", err)
    }
    return updatedResult.ModifiedCount
}
```

The content of UpdateMyData method is fine cause it simply accepts bson and call UpdateOne method to update data into database and works for all different fields I have properly.

The problem is *time.Now().UnixNane()* returning *int64* value, the above code does not throw an error, but it changes the "type" of **lastUpdated** to *Int64* inside my MongoDb database for that specific row! So what is the correct way of passing data into timestamp field, without changing its type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing a timestamp instead of int64:

```
"lastUpdate": primitive.Timestamp{T:uint32(time.Now().Unix())}
```

Note that mongodb timestamp is unix seconds, not nanoseconds.

Comment: Thank you, just to make this work, I had to cast this to unit32, primitive.Timestamp{T:uint32(time.Now().Unix())} }. Otherwise, the compiler was giving me an error.

Comment: Some sources say that `primitive.Timestamp` is for internal use in MongoDB only. `primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime` is recommended instead.